# How to do lookup for AID values in EID column for same EUID and PID using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to do lookup for AID values in EID column for same EUID and PID using SQL query? If AID value is present in EID column for same EUID and PID then it will be excluded from result or it will be returned in result set.

Below is the table and expected Result

```
+------+-----+-------+-------+
| EUID | PID |  AID  |  EID  |
+------+-----+-------+-------+
|  100 |  10 |  1000 |  2000 |
|  100 |  10 |  1000 |  3000 |
|  100 |  10 |  2000 |  3000 |
|  200 |  20 |  4000 |  5000 |
|  200 |  20 |  5000 |  4000 |
|  300 |  30 |  6000 |  8000 |
|  300 |  30 |  6000 |  7000 |
|  300 |  30 |  7000 |  8000 |
|  300 |  30 |  7000 |  6000 |
|  400 |  40 |  9000 | 10000 |
|  400 |  40 | 10000 |  9000 |
|  400 |  40 | 11000 | 12000 |
+------+-----+-------+-------+
```

Required Result

```
+--------+-------+-------+
|  EUID  |  PID  |  AID  |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    100 | 10    |  1000 |
|    400 | 40    | 11000 |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dale Hi Dale, Thanks for asking. I can't show it because it is from work but the table you are seeing is not actually a table but that is the result I am getting after joining and creating some temporary tables. This is the last step where I want to do group by EUID and PID but don't know how to look up the AID values in EID for each EUID and PID. New to SQL learning. I hope now you believe that I have tried.

Comment: That makes sense to me. I will do that going forward. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OUTER APPLY to find out the missing EUIDs and then use DISTINCT to reduce duplicates.

```sql
DECLARE @t table(EUID int, PID int,  AID  int,  EID int)

INSERT INTO @t values
(100 ,  10 ,  1000 ,  2000 ),
(100 ,  10 ,  1000 ,  3000 ),
(100 ,  10 ,  2000 ,  3000 );

SELECT distinct ot.EUID, ot.pid, ot.AID FROM @t as ot
OUTER APPLY
(
select it.EID
from @T AS IT
where it.euid = ot.euid
and it.pid = ot.pid
and it.eid = ot.aid) as presencecheck
WHERE presencecheck.EID is null
```

```
+------+-----+------+
| EUID | pid | AID  |
+------+-----+------+
|  100 |  10 | 1000 |
+------+-----+------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Venkatraman. It worked as expected to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `not exists` :

```
select euid, pid, aid
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.euid = t.euid and
                        t2.eid = t.pid
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon. It worked well but missed out few records, may be because I didn't put those records in example.

Comment: @Raja . . . This answers the question that you asked.